# rowData.forEach() is not a function in ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular

I'm using ag-grid in my angular application and trying to retrieve data from json file using ag-grid, but it is showing error as rowData.forEach is not a function. Able to understand that rowData is accepting json object instead of json array but actually I'm passing json array

json data:

```
[
        {
            "labelGuid": "991bjs",
            "request": "Select Opposing Party Separator",
            "taskAvailableCount": 2
        },
        {
            "labelGuid": "123fgh",
            "request": "What is the page number?",
            "taskAvailableCount": 20
        }
]
```

Couldn't find the actual problem for this. Can I get any solution?
[rowData_error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSJfg.png)

Comment: rowData is probably a single object of your array. for example `{ "labelGuid": "991bjs", "request": "Select Opposing Party Separator", "taskAvailableCount": 2 }`.  so `rowData.labelGuid === '991bjs'`

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also post the code that is giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give more information. 
**rowData** probably is not an array in your case, that`s why you have an error:

> rowData.forEach is not a function